# Excel Scatter Diagram

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data in Excel as follows (just example of them, not all):

```
Name   |  Asset  | Count
----------------------------- 
John   | Apple   | 1
Adam   | Banana  | 2
Pete   | Apple   | 1
Mark   | Berry   | 5
Jeremy | Berry   | 3
Alex   | Banana  | 4
```

Now I need to create graph as follows using Scatter Chart:

```
Mark                      O
Alex             O  
Jeremy                    o
Adam             o  
Pete    o       
John    o       
      Apple   Banana    Berry
```

I can't get it work. Is it possible to do graph easily like this? Can you point me to the right direction? No addon should be used.

Comment: Please explain what you're doing already, what you click on and what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel charts need numbers to plot data, not text. Some Excel charts accept text values for the X axis categories, like column charts or line charts, but the Y axis (the value axis) must always be a number.

Excel XY scatter charts need numbers for both the X and the Y axis.

You will need to create a chart data source that represents your text values as numbers, i.e. John = 1, Pete = 2, Adam = 3 on the Y axis. Along the same lines, Apple = 1, Banana = 2, Berry = 3 on the X axis. This can be done with a pivot table. Unfortunately, a pivot table does not support XY Scatter charts. You will need to build a data source that references the pivot table.

You can use a Bubble chart to size the data points, but you will need to create a separate data set for that.

With this setup, the X and Y axes will show the data values, not the text values. You can fix that by adding additional data series to the chart that sit at the required positions and then use the free XY Chart Labeler add-in by Rob Bovey to  place the labels for the chart.

The add-in is available here: http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm